# Is there a way to enable queue runner activity debug log entries without elevating logging for everything else?

Tags: email-server, sendmail

I'm trying to troubleshoot why a queue runner process terminated unexpectedly.  Is there a way I can elevate logging for queue runner activity in Sendmail without adding extra debugging for other unnecessary stuff?

I know there are debug switches I could use when launching from the command-line but since I'm not sure if/when this will happen again, I was hoping to add something to the `sendmail.mc` that would have the daemon itself log the extra stuff starting at launch/reboot.

Or another way to phrase this question: Can I set/define debug switches within sendmail.mc?

Comment: Have you considered using cron entries to schedule/start queue runs instead of command line options passed to main sendmail daemon?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip yes, and we're using that as a workaround however I want to determine root cause for why the original queue runner failed.